# PayPal POST Variables Not Being Returned Following Purchase

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've recently been able to successfully complete a purchase with the PayPal Sandbox and had POST variables available after the purchase, which redirects to a submission form page (which should only be viewable after payment) on payment:

```
array(30) { ["payer_email"]=> string(36) "example@personal.example.com" ["payer_id"]=> string(13) "4FUN7NBSC787C" ["payer_status"]=> string(8) "VERIFIED" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "John" ["last_name"]=> string(3) "Doe" ["address_name"]=> string(12) "Tester Tests" ["address_street"]=> string(12) "3000 Pine St" ["address_city"]=> string(7) "Testing" ["address_country_code"]=> string(2) "GB" ["address_zip"]=> string(8) "SW1A 1AA" ["residence_country"]=> string(2) "GB" ["txn_id"]=> string(17) "4JL40298VT457961L" ["mc_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["mc_fee"]=> string(4) "0.33" ["mc_gross"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["protection_eligibility"]=> string(8) "ELIGIBLE" ["payment_fee"]=> string(4) "0.33" ["payment_gross"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["payment_status"]=> string(9) "Completed" ["payment_type"]=> string(7) "instant" ["handling_amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["shipping"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["txn_type"]=> string(10) "web_accept" ["payment_date"]=> string(20) "2020-07-19T20:05:47Z" ["business"]=> string(36) "example@business.example.com" ["receiver_id"]=> string(13) "LTCCDM4GCQZKW" ["notify_version"]=> string(11) "UNVERSIONED" ["custom"]=> string(11) "alreadyPaid" ["verify_sign"]=> string(56) "AcUCovblmWr2tKRnFCWWVIV11FyiA6BhiCk05j3nsD6ht3wW7G7A4Jxa" }
```

I inserted the following code within the "Advanced Variables" section of the button to do this:

```
return=https://example.com/submit-details-test/
rm=2
custom=alreadyPaid
```

However, when I attempt to make a live purchase with a real PayPal account with a real payment button, inserting the same code (changing the return URL to reflect my actual site) within the "Advanced Variables", the POST array is empty on return.

I, at the very least, need that custom variable `alreadyPaid` to be returned so we can verify that a person has paid before letting them view the form submission page.

Are there specific settings that must be set in the live PayPal account to use this (or can I not receive POST data back on the return URL, but only through setting up IPN?)?

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML standard payments you are using, a return is never guaranteed to happen. Depending on the buyer, PayPal may be obligated to show them a receipt, and they may not click to return, or their browser could crash. So, even if you were receiving post data, you should never be relying on or doing anything important with this.

An asynchronous IPN can theoretically be relied on since it is a separate communication directly from PayPal to your server, but that communication could always be delayed or also fail.

The only solution that guarantees your server is notified of completed payments is a server-side integration of PayPal checkout, using this front-end UI:  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

For that you need two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/